# Windows 7 Glitches When Enter is Pressed

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-word, virus

There are currently two situations where I have a bug, and was wondering if it is a known virus. First of all is when I'm hitting enter in a URL bar, it just spams a bunch of random characters. The other situation is when I'm trying to start a new paragraph in a word editor (word, google docs, wordpad, notepad), it just deletes everything.

If you've heard of this error/glitch happening at all please do tell me, and is there any fix to it?

Answer (score 1):

It never hurts to run an anti-virus / anti malware software.

This could be a hardware, or driver problem, though. We could use more information, if you don't mind. What have you tried?

Try plugging in another keyboard - my PC used to keep pressing F9 all the time, causing all sorts of problems until I replaced the keyboard. If nothing else, at least we can rule it out.

Do you play games? Have you tried playing a game that uses the keyboard? Does it recognize your keystrokes?

When entering into the URL bar, you said it inputs a bunch of random characters. What do they look like? Random US / English Characters, or something else entirely? Is there a pattern to the random characters?

If I were to guess, I'd say it's one of the following:

- Enter key is broken, hits a few other keys in its stead. I once had a keyboard that had the switches under D and F broken, but only when another key is pressed. Pressing D or F does nothing, but pressing Ctrl + F (Find) saves my current webpage as a bookmark (Ctrl + D)
- Something wrong with Windows mapping the Enter key

In any case, keep us posted on further developments. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem with your internal key mapper. I would first check your hardware drivers from your computer companies site (try the keyboard driver first and then anything that you would think to intermingle) and if that doesn't solve anything, you can download a key mapper to disable or reassign keys to produce different bindings.

edit: plus it wouldn't hurt to run anti-malware and anti-virus software.